# Integrate existing yaml file in a .md document

Tags: mkdocs

I am looking for a way to integrate an existing yaml file in a .md document. the yaml file resides in a gitub repo and can also be accessed relative to the .md file (for example ../dir/test.yaml)
I am using mkdocs for my site.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `mkdocs-include-markdown-plugin` which is added using: `pip install --no-cache-dir mkdocs-include-markdown-plugin`

Then enable it in `mkdocs.yml`:

```yaml
plugins:
  - include-markdown
```

Now use:

```
Include relative text:

{% include "../test.yml" %}

Include relative markdown:

{% include-markdown "../README.md" %}
```

Read more about it under https://github.com/mondeja/mkdocs-include-markdown-plugin or see it on my examples https://alinex.gitlab.io/lang/mkdocs.html#include which are build using https://alinex.gitlab.io/docker-mkdocs/.